# How to clear unused linked-data (libraries) quickly

Tags: linked-data, blend-files

I've got several assets files, which for some reason have unused linked-materials (from external other files). This results in a **big list** of useless "Libraries", visible in the Outliner, "*Blender file*" type of information.

I tried to delete the materials **by hand**, with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *Click* on the "Unlink datablock" button, save the file, then reopen it, but materials are still there.

[image: unused linked materials]

However, I tried to **change the path** of the linked libs by a non-existing file, directly in the Outliner, then saved the file and reopen it (twice). It worked. But **too long and fastidious** way to do that...

[image: useless libraries list]

My question is : is there a **quick way** (with scripting or via UI) to auto-unlink unused things ?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any 'fake' users - the F button next to the material name?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure... I added some images to the question to illustrate. BTW, the linked materials seems to have users. I guess it's the linked file's users, because in this scene there is no object who use those materials, just 1 object with the packed material ("Metal_Ancre").

Comment: Is there any progress with the script, is there anything so far, probably you **Plosson** are very busy I guess, I have similar issue - I would go forward, what you think, is there any possibility to change this path in .blend file direct in python, without opening in Blender. Cause in my case there is a kind of BUG which makes the .blend file crash on open.. What do you think guys?? http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360517-Please-help

Comment: Polosson did you finished your "group cleaner" script?

Comment: Hey @jay27flow and Ivaylo, the script I made to clean uninstanciated groups and their libraries is [downloadable here](http://www.polosson.com/public/scripts/AutoClean_groups.py.zip). Use it carefully! Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender does not save unlinked datablocks. Thus linked datablock always has a user in the file it was linked from. To remove from your scene you must first click the make local button [image] and then it can be unlinked [image]

Comment: Well, you're right, even if I knew it, I just realized that the users of those materials were some *un*instantiated groups. By right-clicking on those groups in the Outliner, and choose "Unlink group" on each, then save, linked materials disappeared. Thx, btw!

Comment: Here's a script to auto-unlink groups that are not instantiated, and their libraries: http://www.polosson.com/public/scripts/AutoClean_groups.py.zip