# How to Remove a Fake User?

Tags: materials

I have a material I no longer need, but it has a 'fake' user attached. I don't see any way to remove the fake user so the material can be garbage-collected out.

Someone in [another answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/how-to-clear-unused-linked-data-libraries-quickly) on here talked about a "Make Local" button which could (apparently) do this disconnect, but I don't see that button anywhere. Where should I be looking?

Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-completely-remove-an-image-from-my-blend-file

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

1. Assign the material to an object,
2. Shift-Click the 'X' to remove it, and
3. Save the file, then
4. Revert.

Voila. It's gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to improve the situation. Here what's happens:

1. This post is the first in line googling "blender remove fake user"
2. The only answer here is a workaround, that didn't work for me (using a recent version of Blender : 3.0), probably because back in time, it was the only way to do.
3. **There is a valid and detailed answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/142340/141535)**, as suggested [Paul Gonet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/7797/paul-gonet)
4. This answer is not the one that was selected by the other question author either.