# Remove a linked Indirect Library datablock

Tags: linked-data, data-blocks

I am trying to remove a texture data block from a file. It seems to have been put there by an addon that is no longer installed. The texture block is a Linked block, originally linked in from a file in the addon's folder. Normally you could click the link icon to make it local, then set users to zero. However, the link icon is greyed out, and when highlighted says "Indirect library data-block, cannot change."

[image]

The texture's data block also shows up under Orphan Data in the outliner, but all its options are greyed out.

[image]

How do I fully delete this?

Comment: Did you try Purge All to remove it? What about Shift+X clicking on the name of texture datablock in UV editor? (then save+reopen)

Comment: Shift clicking the X button in the UV editor deselected it there, but does not remove it. Purge all does not help as it thinks it has a user, although I cannot find what it is.

Comment: There is set fake user which will prevent purging, but this should be overcome with Shift+X hence why I proposed it. Though I didn't try to work it with indirect libraries. Try maybe here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2331/how-to-clear-unused-linked-data-libraries-quickly

Comment: Since the Make Local button is greyed out, I can't do this. I also tried the AutoClean_groups script they mention in the comments, and it did not seem to do anything.